# show images in disorder by the ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

you can see part of my code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="commentItem in comments track by $index">
    <div style="float: left; width: 15%;;">
      <img width="100%" src="{{commentItem.headImage}}">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="comment.loadMore" on-infinite="loadMoreComments()">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

when the 'comments' contains less  data ,all looks normal.But when there are lots of data in the array(maybe 100 or more),the images will be showed in disorder.For example, the image should be  in the  third "li" will be showed in the fourth "li".Could anyone tell me why,please!
PS. I use the ionic.bundle.js,but I dont know it will cause something wrong or not. And when the event of ion-infinite-scroll be tiggered,I will push the new data into the "comments" array.

Comment: I didn't find your code, may you send again?

Comment: I have just edit my text.Now you can read the code,please^_^

Comment: Sorry man, but i think that it's not enough... Can you put more information?

Answer (score 1):

Tracking by $index is not a good idea. Can you track by commentItem.id (or another unique identifier on the commentItem) instead? I'm not sure if that will solve the problem but looking at that code snippet, that's the first thing I would try.